# det(A)det(B) = det(AB+correction), Capelli identities, "factorized" representation of $\mathfrak {gl}_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, co.combinatorics, determinants

**Context:** Some probably know that there are [Capelli identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capelli's_identity) which state
$$det(A)det(B) = det(AB+correction)$$ for some matrices with non-commuting elements, they go back to the 19-th century, but also investigated up to present due relations with representation theory, [quantum integrable systems](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610799), etc. In a forthcoming paper I will discuss a more general question/conjecture on 
$det(A+correction)det(B+correction) = det(AB+correction)$. But I understand that
there is quite a simple question to ask, which seems to be open. So let me ask it here.

**Notation:** Consider two finite sets of commuting variables, $\{a_i\}$ and  another set $\{b_j\}$, but $[a_i, b_j] \ne 0$, more precisely let us require the following commutation relations:

Denote $E_{ij}:=a_i b_j$ and require that $$[E_{ij}, E_{kl} ] = \delta_{jk}E_{il}-\delta_{li}E_{kj},$$ i.e. the same relations as satisfied by the "matrix units" $e_{ij}$,
i.e. matrices having 1 at position $(i,j)$ and zeros everywhere else.

**Question:** Is it true that for $n>1$, $$det^{column}(E+diag(n-1,n-2, ..., 1,0)) = 0 \ ?$$
Here $E$ is the matrix with elements $E_{ij}$ at position $(i,j)$, and $det^{column}$ means that
we use the usual definition of the determinant, but the elements of the first column come first
in the products, second column = second, etc.

**Motivation:** If $a,b$ were commuting variables then $E$ would be a matrix of rank 1
and its determinant equal to zero. The correction $+diag(n-1,n-2, ..., 1,0)$ is the usual
correction for the Capelli type identities.

**Checks:** For 2x2 matrices  I have checked it. If the commutation relations are
$[a_i, b_j]=-\delta_{ij}$ then it is also known to be true as a part of the modern Capelli story. I.e. if $b_j = \partial_{a_j}$ we get the standard construction of the $S^*(C^n)$ 
representation of $\mathfrak {gl}_n$ by differential operators.

**Subquestion:** The 3x3 case is not easy to check by hand, may be it is possible to check it by some software ?

Comment: I would suggest to see if this is true even when you consider non-commutative variables $E_{ij}$ that are not necessarily of the form $a_ib_j$. 

Comment: Damien, thank you for your comment however I a little disagree - if E_{ij} not of this form, but say of E is "full rank matrix" we will get det(A)det(B) and it is not equal to zero, but conjectural generalization of classical Capelli identity. It should be zero when A,B are  of small rank. I will put it as question 2 later...

Comment: I think your question follows from Proposition 1.2 (a) in [Sergio Caracciolo, Alan D. Sokal, Andrea Sportiello, *Noncommutative determinants, Cauchy-Binet formulae, and Capelli-type
identities, I*](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v16i1r103) (see also [my errata](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/ncd-errata.pdf)) when applied to the following setting: $m = n$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and ...

Comment: ... $B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $r = n$ and $I = \left[n\right]$ and $J = \left[n\right]$. Can you confirm?

Comment: Okay, perhaps not quite. Your $\left[E_{ij},E_{kl}\right]$ relations don't imply the relations (1.8) in that paper. But perhaps the proof they give still applies.